# Calling static function pointer from static method

Tags: c++

I have the following code in my Individual.hpp file:

```
typedef string (Individual::*getMethodName)(void);    
static getMethodName currentFitnessMethodName;
static string getCurrentFitnessMethodName();
```

And this on my .cpp file:

```
string Individual::getCurrentFitnessMethodName(){
    return (Individual::*currentFitnessMethodName)();
}
```

I'm using function pointers in other parts of my code but always in the same object context, so I do (this->*thingyMajigger)(params), but with that static call I get the following error:

**Expected unqualified-id**

I have tried multiple permutations of said code but none seem to work. Can anyone share some light?

Cheers

Comment: Being a pointer to non-static member function, `currentFitnessMethodName` requires an `Individual` object to be called on.  In your static function `getCurrentFitnessMethodName`, there is no `this` pointer.  Do you have another `Individual` object you can use there?

Comment: Why are you using static and function pointer instead of just doing it correctly with object.method?

Comment: @aschepler, no I don't. I just described that as an example.

Comment: @stark because the value of that pointer is variable depending on certain params. And since the point is not needing the object to use this function, I can't do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your typedef is what's messing you up. Static methods are just regular functions that just happen to have access to protected/private static members of their class.

Change the typedef to simply:

```
typedef string (*getMethodName)(void);
```

The former syntax is for non-static member methods.

---

As an example, the following doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Foo {
public:
    typedef string (Foo::*staticMethod)();

    static staticMethod current;

    static string ohaiWorld() {
        return "Ohai, world!";
    }

    static string helloWorld() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

    static string callCurrent() {
        return Foo::current();
    }
};

Foo::staticMethod Foo::current = &Foo::ohaiWorld;

int main() {
    cout << Foo::callCurrent() << endl;
    Foo::current = &Foo::helloWorld;
    cout << Foo::callCurrent() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But changing the typedef from

```
typedef string (Foo::*staticMethod)();
```

to

```
typedef string (*staticMethod)();
```

allows it to compile - and as expected it outputs:

```
Ohai, world!
Hello, world!
```